# Using intermediate variables for ternary operator (or similar) for better performance?

Tags: c++, optimization

Assume in C++ (or C, Java, etc.) I have code like this:

```
int a = f() > g() ? f() : g();
```

which of course assigns **a** with the greater between return values of f() and g(). Now assuming f() and g() are themselves complex and slow, should I replace this line with something like

```
int f_value = f();
int g_value = g();
int a = f_value > g_value ? f_value : g_value;
```

so neither f() and g() will be called twice, or is the compiler (given sufficient optimization) going to do something like this for me anyway so I don't have to do anything?

This general question of course applies to many similar scenarios as well.

Comment: consider `int a = std::max( f(), g() );`

Comment: gcc allows to set attribute `pure` ([docu](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html)). If `f` and `g` are specified this way the compile can optimize your code.

Comment: @ClaasBontus, Thank you so much. I just read the doc of gcc about pure attribute and it seems to be exactly what I was expecting.

Comment: Never mind performance. What about legibility, clarity, maintainability? If you are unsure how the code works now, how will you, or someone else (hopefully not me), feel when looking at it a year from now?

Answer (score 34):

Generally, no, the compiler won't do it – it can't, actually. Calling f and g could have side effects, and the result of the second call of either f or g might not be the same as in the first call. Imagine something like this:

```
int f()
{
    static int n = 0;
    return ++n;
}
```

But there are exceptions proving the rule:

Actually, a compiler is allowed to perform *any* optimisation it wants to – *as long as* the optimised code behaves exactly the same (considering any *visible* effects) as the completely unoptimised one.

So if the compiler can guarantee that omitting the second function call does not suppress any side effects (and only then!), it actually is allowed to optimise the second call away and most likely will do so, too, at higher optimisation levels.

Comment: Also maybe `f()` and `g()` are using some global variable and before `f()` is called the second time the global variable has been modified by first `g()` call.

Comment: Thanks, you just reminded this fact which should prevent compiler from doing it at all. So I guess I should use intermediate values no matter how simple the functions can be as a better habbit. Thanks!

Comment: Actually the compiler sometimes can make that oprimization, because it often knows the implementation of f and g

Comment: You first say the compiler won't optimize it and then say it most likely will. So which is it?

Comment: @DDrmmr In general, it won't, because of possible side effects. But there are exceptions proving the rule, i. e. if the compiler detects that a function has no side effects with absolute, 100% security, then, and only then, he can leave the second function call out. And only then he is likely to do so. And: both functions have to be considered independently, possibly optimising away the second call of only one of them as the other one has side effects or the compiler cannot prove that there aren't any. – Aconcagua 1 hour ago

Comment: @GauravSehgal: Note that for C++, it's unspecified (and possibly not consistent) in which order the function calls are made.

Comment: @Peng No, that is not necessarily a better habit. Readable code is a good habit. Profiling before optimization is a good habit. Using the standard library functions made for this purpose is a good habit. If, *and only if*, this line becomes a bottleneck, then you can investigate ways to fix it. Even then, you may find that you are only seeing symptoms of a deeper problem, like function calls not being inlined, or vectorization not happening.

Comment: @MSalters Can you please elaborate on this.

Comment: @GauravSehgal The C++ compiler is free to decide, if it first evaluates f(), then g() and then calls operator> -- or first g(), then f() and then operator>. Same is with `h(f(), g())`, again it is implementation defined if either f or g is evaluated first. Standard only requests that both f and g complete execution before h is called. Should be the same for C, only that > is a built-in operator that cannot be overloaded (so no explicit `operator>` exists).

Comment: @Aconcagua So this difference in c and c++ arises because c++ supports operator overloading while c does not.Right?

Comment: @GauravSehgal There is no difference in C and C++, if operator> is a built-in one (e. g. because of f and g both returning int). If one of f and g returns a value enforcing the use of an overloaded operator, an extra sequence point is added before entering the operator. But still, f and g both are sequenced before the operator starts execution (new C++ wording) and thus can be called in arbitrary order. Effectively, there would be two sequence points one after another without any code in between (old wording again).

Comment: @Aconcagua Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 19):

**TL;DR**: there are functions called `min` and `max`...

---

The compiler may, or may not, perform this optimization for you.

From the compiler point of view, `f() > g() ? f() : g()` is likely to be:

```
entry:
    _0 = f();
    _1 = g();
    _cmp = _0 > _1
    if _cmp: goto _greater; else: goto _lesser;

greater:
    _2 = f();
    goto end;

lesser:
    _3 = g();
    goto end;

end:
   phi [greater _2], [lesser _3]
```

This is called SSA form (Static Single Assignment form), and is used by most optimizers such as LLVM and gcc.

Whether the compiler evaluates `f()` or `g()` once or twice will depend on whether:

- `f()` and `g()` are either annotated as `pure` or evaluated to be `pure` (no side effects, result solely depending on inputs)
- or `f()` and `g()` are inlined at the call side
- or...

In general, I would not count on it.

---

However, all of this does not matter.

There are *higher-level* functions to do what you want, such as `max` here:

```
int a = std::max(f(), g());
```

guarantees, in C++, that it will only ever evaluate `f()` and `g()` once (the order of evaluation is not guaranteed, but both will be evaluated only once, and before the call to `max` itself).

This is strictly equivalent to:

```
int _0 = f();
int _1 = g();
int a = std::max(_0, _1);
```

but of course, much slicker.

Comment: Be aware that Microsoft's <Windows.h> define `max` as a macro, which makes `max(f(), g())` still call f or g twice. `(std::max)(f(), g())` is a workaround.

Comment: @jingyu9575: ugh... I am suddenly glad not to develop on windows... I would have hoped they would write the macro in a way that a single evaluation would occur...

Comment: Windows `#define max` is another reason to always explicitly use `std::max`, as at least you get a compiler error instead of a bug.

Comment: @Yakk: very true. I suitably amended the example :)

Comment: Sometimes it looks like MS developers break any good practice just for fun. I think any normal company would fire an idiot who would make macro lowercase especially with such a common name.

Comment: Sorry if offended someone using PC incorrect term. I should say "alternatively talented" person.

Comment: @jingyu9575 That was a poor decision by them, but at least they provided a way to disable those macros: simply `#define NOMINMAX` around the `#include` of that header. Also, out of interest, why/do you need the extra parentheses around `std::max`?

Comment: There are evidences that the employee who developed that `max` macro is still getting GIT blames for his birthday for having introduced that macro.

Comment: @underscore_d: If you write `std::max(x, y)` then `max(x, y)` is macro-expanded (because tokens) leaving you with `std::((x) < (y) ? (y) : (x))`. By using extra parentheses around `std::max`, you prevent the macro from kicking in. Disabling them is of course even better.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Thanks, maybe it's a good thing that I haven't used macros in so much depth yet ;-)

Comment: @DarioOO: the huge news there is that Microsoft uses `git`.

Comment: @SteveJessop I was just joking XD, do you think Microsoft use SVN then? XD

Answer (score 9):

"Given sufficient optimization" the compiler *might* do it, depending on the characteristics of the functions `f` and `g`. If the compiler can see the definitions of the functions (so either they're in the same TU they're called from or you're using link time optimization), and can see that they have no side-effects and their results don't depend on any globals, then it can evaluate them only once instead of twice.

If they do have side effects, then you've demanded that they be called twice and so one of them will be evaluated twice.

If they're `constexpr`, it could call them no times.

For your example, using `std::max(f(), g())` is generally more convenient than using intermediate variables. Like any function call it only evaluates each argument once.

Given this code:

```
int f(int x) {
    return x + 1;
}

int g(int x) {
    return x + 2;
}

int foo(int a, int b) {
    return f(a) > g(b) ? f(a) : g(b);
}
```

gcc -O0 on my machine produces the following. Even if you can't read it, observe that `callq <_Z1fi>` occurs twice:

```
        int foo(int a, int b) {
  1e:   55                      push   %rbp
  1f:   53                      push   %rbx
  20:   48 83 ec 28             sub    $0x28,%rsp
  24:   48 8d ac 24 80 00 00    lea    0x80(%rsp),%rbp
  2b:   00
  2c:   89 4d c0                mov    %ecx,-0x40(%rbp)
  2f:   89 55 c8                mov    %edx,-0x38(%rbp)
                return f(a) > g(b) ? f(a) : g(b);
  32:   8b 4d c0                mov    -0x40(%rbp),%ecx
  35:   e8 c6 ff ff ff          callq  0 <_Z1fi>
  3a:   89 c3                   mov    %eax,%ebx
  3c:   8b 45 c8                mov    -0x38(%rbp),%eax
  3f:   89 c1                   mov    %eax,%ecx
  41:   e8 c9 ff ff ff          callq  f <_Z1gi>
  46:   39 c3                   cmp    %eax,%ebx
  48:   7e 0a                   jle    54 <_Z3fooii+0x36>
  4a:   8b 4d c0                mov    -0x40(%rbp),%ecx
  4d:   e8 ae ff ff ff          callq  0 <_Z1fi>
  52:   eb 0a                   jmp    5e <_Z3fooii+0x40>
  54:   8b 45 c8                mov    -0x38(%rbp),%eax
  57:   89 c1                   mov    %eax,%ecx
  59:   e8 b1 ff ff ff          callq  f <_Z1gi>
        }
  5e:   48 83 c4 28             add    $0x28,%rsp
  62:   5b                      pop    %rbx
  63:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  64:   c3                      retq
```

whereas gcc -O2 produces:

```
        int foo(int a, int b) {
                return f(a) > g(b) ? f(a) : g(b);
  20:   8d 42 02                lea    0x2(%rdx),%eax
  23:   83 c1 01                add    $0x1,%ecx
  26:   39 c1                   cmp    %eax,%ecx
  28:   0f 4d c1                cmovge %ecx,%eax
        }
  2b:   c3                      retq
```

Since it can see the definitions of `f` and `g`, the optimizer has had its way with them.

Comment: Definitely +1 for mention of contexpr. I expect that contexpr would allow this to be optimised to a single call even in the cases of non const arguments due to the restraints of contexpr on not changing global state. Probably worth mentioning that.